# Check if a user is a regular user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model

I have the following code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  named_scope :regular_users, :conditions => { :is_developer => false }
end
```

How can I change this code to return if a specific user is a regular user (has :is_developer => false ) instead of a list of all regular users?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just check `User.find(1).is_developer?` (actually it will work even without the `?`)
To check the opposite, use `! User.find(1).is_developer?` or `not User.find(1).is_developer`

or put this in a model method like

```
def is_regular?
  ! is_developer?
end
```

I doubt that you can get boolean value with scope.

btw, with Rails3 you can use `scope` instead of `named_scope`

Comment: if I create a model method it will do. self.is_developer ? for the current User?

Comment: It will work for any User instance. You could create a helper that will always check the current_user

Comment: hint: put this in your helpers/application_helper: `def is_regular? current_user.is_regular? end` :)

Comment: and then I will be able to use is_regular in views as well?

Comment: Sure. That's exactly what helpers are for. There's a gotcha. I guess you should wrap the helper code with `if user_signed_in?`. Otherwise it will probably throw an error when user is not signed in.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. It's a facebook app. So I already have a check if a user is an authorized user:)